# What would be an effective way to call a function with arguments from a list in python

Tags: python

My current code is similar to the following.

```
    def func(args):
        optionalparameters = ((args.split(':')[1]).split(' '))[1:]
        second_func(optionalparameters)
```

This assumes `args` is a colon-separated string; it takes the second half, splits it into space-delimited words and returns (a list of?) all but the first. The situation where more than one colon is included isn't yet handled, because I am new to the language.

Can the optional_parameters be passed not as a list? Since parameters are optional will the following be effective?

```
    def func(args):
        optionalparameters = ((args.split(':')[1]).split(' '))[1:]
        val1=val2=val3=None
        try:
            val1 = optionalparameters[0]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            val2 = optionalparameters[1]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:    
            val3 = optionalparameters[2]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        second_func(val1, val2, val3)
```

It seems likely that standard library modules might be able to do much of this. Any help in argument handling is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I think you may just want `second_func(*optionalparameters)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters

Comment: Ty @larsks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `unpack` the values from the list:

```
optionalparameters = ((args.split(':')[1]).split(' '))[1:]
second_func(*optionalparameters)
```

or:

```
val1, val2, val3=((args.split(':')[1]).split(' '))[1:]    
second_func(val1, val2, val3)
```